# MigrationError during plone upgrading from 4.3.8 to 5.0.3

Tags: migration, plone, plone-5.x

OS: debian 8.3

I upgraded partially from 4.3.8 to 5.0.3. I get stuck in migration error to Dexterity.

**The process I did before upgrade in 4.3.8:**

1. Disable  all  add-ons
2. Add a sitecustomize.py in site-package director:
   import sys
   sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
3. update and re-index all catalog in keti/portal_catalog/manage_main
4. delete  'checkout_workflow_policy'  in  keti/portal_properties/site_properties/manage_propertiesForm
5. delete all objects in /keti/reference_catalog/manage_catalogView

**The process of upgrading:**

1.Clean Install of Plone 5.0.3
2.Copy database from existing server (plone 4.3.8), along with blobstorage to the Plone 5.0.3 server.
3.Run upgrade
During this, all look good(report in http://pastie.org/10787693) except 2 invalid import handlers:
   **Step collective.z3cform.datetimewidget has an invalid import handler
   **Step languagetool has an invalid import handler
4. On the upgrade page Click “Upgrade your existing content to use Dexterity”(@@pac_installer). Then I can visit the instance.
5. Click to Install dexterity. It works except a message on the topline of the page:
*error while rendering plone.resourceregistries.scripts error while rendering plone.resourceregistries.styles*

**6. In Migration control panel page,  BlobFile, Document and Folder were selected to migrate.

After a long waiting, errors pop up (http://pastie.org/10787685)**

**Event.log: http://pastie.org/10792956**

**Newest Progress：**

Good news: I click on " Show country-specific language variants " in /@@language-controlpanel, then select "simplified chinese" in the language list. So the problem of ConstraintNotSatisfied is resolved. Now I go back to the first problem: MigrationError: MigrationError for obj at /keti/switch/shbpsh/2010/2010ybps There is no content rules in the server and I disabled globally.)

Add-ons activated in 4.3.8: Diazo theme support, Dexterity Content Types, collective.z3cform.datetimewidget, Static resource storage

Any suggestion?

Best Regards.

Hugo

Comment: Your pastie event log link is no more

Comment: Your error message seems related to a content rule... if you can, try to delete your content rules or check if you have issues with them.
**Please note**: your "process I did before upgrade in 4.3.8" make no sense! You don't need to uninstall your add-ons! You must not **never** use `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`! Why you are cleaning the reference catalog??

Comment: A little step forward: I delete the folder then the migration success. But another problem come out: ConstraintNotSatisfied: ('zh-cn', 'language') in /keti/dexterity-types/File/@@fields . The same to all dexterity types. Full traceback in http://pastie.org/10790599.

Comment: Thanks keul.  There is no content rules in the server and I disabled globally.

Answer (score 0):

After deleted the folder cited in MigrationError, I finally upgrade the server to 5.0.4. Then I will perform a testing.