# How to deal with these difference in the upgraded plone instance(from 4.3.8 to 5.0.4) and the new created instance(5.0.4)?

Tags: plone

Yesterday, I upgraded finally a plone instance from 4.3.8 to 5.0.4. (ref. [MigrationError during plone upgrading from 4.3.8 to 5.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456798/migrationerror-during-plone-upgrading-from-4-3-8-to-5-0-3/36676869#36676869)).
But after a detailed check, compared to a new created instance in plone 5.0.4, I found some strange conditions in the upgraded instance(from 4.3.8) :

**1. In the page of @@overview-controlpanel:**

(1). There are no icons for caching-controlpanel and dateandtime-controlpanel. But I can access them through the complete url (@@caching-controlpanel and @@dateandtime-controlpanel)

(2). There is a group of “Plone Configuration” in the upgraded instance.

(3). Some items belong to different groups for the upgraded instance and new created instance.
There are many difference between the upgraded instance(from 4.3.8) and new created instance

**2. In the page of ZMI:manage_main:**

(1) Some items exist only in the upgraded instance: 
uid_catalog (Catalog of unique content identifiers), reference_catalog (Catalog of content references), portal_tinymce, portal_placeful_workflow, portal_metadata (Controls metadata like keywords, copyrights, etc), portal_factory (Responsible for the creation of content objects), portal_discussion (Controls how discussions are stored),    portal_atct (Collection and image scales settings), archetype_tool (Archetypes specific settings), portal_undo (Defines actions and functionality related to undo), portal_interface (Allows to query object interfaces), portal_calendar (Controls how events are shown),  portal_actionicons (Associates actions with icons)

(2) In the page of portal_properties, imaging_properties (Image handling properties) only exist in the upgraded instance.

(3) In the page of portal_properties/site_properties, there are more items than the new created instance.

**What can I do to deal with these difference in the upgraded plone instance and the new created instance(5.0.4)? Is the upgraded instance ready for production use?**

Best Regards.

Hugo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. In the page of @@overview-controlpanel:**

I didn't get what you mean with "Some items belong to different groups" but they seems some minor migration issues.
Please provide a [bug request](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.upgrade/issues).

**2. In the page of ZMI:manage_main:**

Keep in mind that an upgrade Plone site from Plone 4 will not **remove** stuff used on Plone 4 because you where probably using it before.
For example the migrated instance will probably have the optional "Archetypes" support installed by default (and this extension create a lot of the tools you find there).
Plone can't know if you are using an Archetypes based add-on not yet migrated to dexterity.

If you later will find that you are not using Archetypes based content types you can probably uninstall the profile and cleanup things.

Comment: 1. In the page of @@overview-controlpanel:

(1). There are no icons for caching-controlpanel and dateandtime-controlpanel. But I can access them through the complete url (@@caching-controlpanel and @@dateandtime-controlpanel)

(2). There is a group of “Plone Configuration” in the upgraded instance.